# Permission denied for GitLab DORA metrics through API

Tags: rest, gitlab, get

I'm trying to access DORA metrics from Gitlab API, but no matter what I try, the response is always

> "You do not have permission to access dora metrics."

I use the following GET request:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/dora/metrics?metric=lead_time_for_changes
(1 is replaced with my project id)

Access token is set to owner and all access.

Comment: What I've found since then is that DORA metrics are only available for premium and elite packages. With free gitlab membership, you don't get DORA metrics.